# How to measure client side performance in single page application

Tags: javascript, performance, rendering, performance-testing

We developed a complex single page application based on Sencha Ext.JS framework.
There are many "pages" in the application that are changing dynamically without refreshing the browser's URL. All the user's interaction and content changing is dynamically created and destroyed.

We now want to measure client side stability and performance along time. The test should focus on client side behavior and responsiveness. We don't need to test the server side response time - it will be same response time for granted during the test.

All the tools that I saw that exists are usually dealing with the XHR response time and usually based on load time per URL which is not relevant on our case - because the same url is continuing and doing work along time.

Any suggestion for a good practice and tools for this kind of test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think that AJAX monitoring and page load time will not help you, then
I can suggest that you can use Transaction monitoring. It can simply done by measuring time between two states or two pages.

**To test locally, using `console.time`**:

```
  console.time('page_name'); 
  // Anything goes here
  console.timeEnd('page_name');
```

**Using `performance.now`**

```
 var start = window.performance.now();
 ...
 var end = window.performance.now();
 var time = end - start;
```

**Using [Atatus](https://www.atatus.com/) service**

If you are looking for service, you can try https://www.atatus.com/ which helps you to measure between transactions in real time.

In atatus, you can measure between transactions or states  by

```
 atatus.beginTransaction("page_name");
 ...
 atatus.endTransaction("page_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like Selenium to automate client behaviour and measure the response time.

Comment: Thanks. I have already an automation for the application this is not the issue. I don't want to measure response time. I'd like to measure javascript responsiveness over time.

Comment: That is exactly what you can do with it. It's not about measuring api calls but anything you'd like. i.e. you can externally invoke your javascript methods ( by simulating a click ) and measure their execution time. Repeat the process hundreds of times to simulate heavy user interaction and measure if JS performance degrades or not.

Comment: I didn't see how Selenium do the JS performance measures and collect the information. Can you point to that?

Comment: You write your own testscripts in selenium so by recording the starttime before you call the browser to perform a task and record the endtime afterwards, you can calculate the elapsed time for that task.